# Помогите поймать ошибку

Tags: c++

Кратко: Есть 3 функции. Они запускаются в разных конфигурациях: 1. функция А - основная функция, она вызывает функцию Б, которая вызывает(уже в своем теле) функцию В, так, что функция В вызывается после всех инструкций функции Б. 2. А - по-прежнему основная функция, но на этот раз она вызывает обе функции(сначала Б, потом В (но при этом Б не вызывает В)). И в первом, и во втором случае входные значения функции В одинаковые. Вопрос состоит в том, почему в обоих случаях результат работы В разный?
От абстракции к коду:
Случай 1.
Функция А:

```
void split_the_file (unsigned char * arr_blocks,
        ifstream & in_f,
        int size_arr, unsigned char (&key)[16], ofstream & of_f){
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.end);
    int end_f = in_f.tellg();
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.beg);
    int current = 0;
    char ch = 0;
    while (!in_f.eof() && ((end_f - current) >= SIZE_OF_BLOCK * SIZE_OF_BLOCK)){
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; j++){
              in_f >> arr_blocks[i*SIZE_OF_BLOCK + j];
           }
           current = in_f.tellg();
      }
      //func cipher uses one block 4*4

      **aes_main(arr_blocks, key);** //Функция Б

      writef (of_f, arr_blocks);
    }
}
```

Функция Б:

```
void aes_main(unsigned char* block,
              unsigned char  (&key)[16]){
    auto new_key = expand_key (key);
    unsigned char* state = new unsigned char[SIZE_OF_BLOCK*SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
    fill_the_state(block, state);
    unsigned char a [16];
    AddRoundKey (new_key, state, 0);

    for (int round = 1; round < Nr; round++){
        SubBytes(state);
        ShiftRows(state);
        MixColomns(state);
        AddRoundKey (new_key, state, round);
    }

    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, state, Nr);

    fill_the_block(block, state);

   **Inv_aes_main(block, key);**//Функция В
    delete (new_key);
    delete (state);
}
```

Функция В:

```
void Inv_aes_main(unsigned char * block, unsigned char  (&key)[16]){
    auto new_key = expand_key (key);
    unsigned char* state = new unsigned char[SIZE_OF_BLOCK*SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
    fill_the_state(block, state);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, state, Nr);
  for (int round = Nr - 1; round > 0; round--){
      InvShiftRows(state);
      InvSubBytes(state);
      AddRoundKey (new_key, state, round);
      InvMixColomns(state);
  }
  InvShiftRows(state);
  InvSubBytes(state);
  AddRoundKey (new_key, state, 0);
  fill_the_block(block, state);
  delete (state);
  delete (new_key);
}
```

Случай 2.
Функция А:

```
void split_the_file (unsigned char * arr_blocks,
        ifstream & in_f,
        int size_arr, unsigned char (&key)[16], ofstream & of_f){
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.end);
    int end_f = in_f.tellg();
    in_f.seekg (0, in_f.beg);
    int current = 0;
    char ch = 0;
    while (!in_f.eof() && ((end_f - current) >= SIZE_OF_BLOCK * SIZE_OF_BLOCK)){
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; j++){
              in_f >> arr_blocks[i*SIZE_OF_BLOCK + j];
           }
           current = in_f.tellg();
      }
      //func cipher uses one block 4*4
      **aes_main(arr_blocks, key);**//Функция Б
      **Inv_aes_main(arr_blocks, key);**//Функция В
     writef (of_f, arr_blocks);
    }

}
```

Функция Б:

```
void aes_main(unsigned char* block,
              unsigned char  (&key)[16]){
    auto new_key = expand_key (key);
    unsigned char* state = new unsigned char[SIZE_OF_BLOCK*SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
    fill_the_state(block, state);
    unsigned char a [16];
    AddRoundKey (new_key, state, 0);

    for (int round = 1; round < Nr; round++){
        SubBytes(state);
        ShiftRows(state);
        MixColomns(state);
        AddRoundKey (new_key, state, round);
    }

    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    AddRoundKey (new_key, state, Nr);
    fill_the_block(block, state);
    delete (new_key);
    delete (state);
}
```

Функция fill_the_block:

```
void fill_the_block (unsigned char * block,
                     unsigned char * state){
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
        for (int  j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; j++){
            block[i*SIZE_OF_BLOCK+j] = state[j*SIZE_OF_BLOCK + i];
        }
    }
}
```

Она служит для заполнения block из массива state по некоторому правилу. Т.е. после этого содержимое block меняется.
Функция fill_the_state:

```
void fill_the_state (unsigned char * block,
        unsigned char * state){
    memset(state,0,SIZE_OF_BLOCK*SIZE_OF_BLOCK);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; i++){
        for (int  j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BLOCK; j++){
            state[j*SIZE_OF_BLOCK + i] = block[i*SIZE_OF_BLOCK+j];
        }
    }
}
```

Функция - по смыслу обратная к fill_the_block.
Выделение памяти под arr_blocks:

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        ifstream in_f;
        ofstream of_f;
        unsigned char key[] = {0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c};
        in_f.open("/home/alex/Загрузки/ciph.txt");
        in_f >> std::noskipws;
        of_f.open("/home/alex/Загрузки/cipher_out.txt");
        in_f.seekg (0, in_f.end);
        int length = in_f.tellg();
        in_f.seekg (0, in_f.beg);
//выделение памяти под массив arr_blocks
        unsigned char* arr = new unsigned char[SIZE_OF_BLOCK*SIZE_OF_BLOCK];
        split_the_file(arr, in_f, SIZE_OF_BLOCK, key, of_f);

        in_f.close();
        of_f.close();
        delete(arr);
        return 0;
    }
```

AddRoundKey:

```
void AddRoundKey(unsigned int *extandedKey, unsigned char *state, int rnd) {
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        state[i]    ^= extandedKey[4*rnd+i] >> 24;
        state[4+i]  ^= extandedKey[4*rnd+i] >> 16;
        state[8+i]  ^= extandedKey[4*rnd+i] >> 8;
        state[12+i] ^= extandedKey[4*rnd+i];
    }
}
```

Функция В та же. Так почему же при одинаковых входных значениях разные выходные? Скорее всего, я не вижу какого-нибудь элементарного бага.

Comment: Ну так, в С++ аргументы могут передаваться по ссылке. Поэтому, например, не видя объявлений функции `fill_the_block` трудно судить о том, не модифицирует ли эта функция свой первый аргумент `block`. Если модифицирует - то тогда неудивительно, что результат получается разный. Показывайте хотя бы объявления остальных функций, в частности - именно `fill_the_block`, `fill_the_state`.

Comment: А память под самый верхний `arr_blocks` правильно выделяется?

Comment: Непонятно... Возможно во вспомогательные функции закралась зависимость от значений указателей? `AddRoundKey`, например...

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду, но одно я выяснил точно: при разных конфигурациях функция AddRoundKey на первом этапе работает по-разному, чего быть не должно.

Comment: Ну так а вылета за пределы массива в `extandedKey[4*rnd+i]` не может быть? А в `state[12+i]`? Что именно возвращает `expand_key`? Чему равно `Nr`? И чему равно `SIZE_OF_BLOCK`?

Comment: Сразу извиняюсь за недосказанность, т.к. проект не маленький, если его полностью добавить, то получится маленький адок. Nr = 10, SIZE_OF_BLOCK = 4

Comment: `Nr=10` означает, что доступ в массив `extandedKey` может идти вплоть до индекса `extandedKey[43]`. Это попадает в размер массива `extandedKey`? Какой массив выделяет `expand_key`?

Comment: Да, т.к. размер extandedKey[44]

Comment: Ну уж не знаю, что и сказать... А как насчет инициализации всех 44 элементов в `expand_key`? Сделано?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что лучше занулить массив мемсетом?

Comment: Ну если в `expand_key` аккуратно инициализируются все 44 возвращаемых элемента, то смысла делать `memset` нет.  Если же `expand_key` *должна* аккуратно инициализировать все 44 возвращаемых элемента, но не делает этого, то `memset` сможет только "замести проблему под ковер", а не починить ее. Посмотреть на реализацию `expand_key` возможно?

Comment: Вы были правы. Я выделяю кусман из кучи, но не зануляю ее. Дело в том, что тому массиву, что я выделяю, не присваиваются значения, а делается +=. Т.е. на деле это все портило, спасибо большое! Вывод: Лучше использовать старый-добрый каллок!

Comment: Зачем каллок? Обычный `new unsigned[44]()` выделит вам сразу обнуленную память (если уж вы не хотите использовать вектор).